# can any one compile label_wav.cc file

Tags: compilation

Linux 16.04

TensorFlow version v2.3

In TensorFlow, I need to compile `label_wav.cc` file.
File location is `tensorflow/examples/speech_commands/label_wav.cc`

I am getting these errors:

```
/usr/local/include/tf/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.pb.h:6451:21: error: ‘struct google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr’ has no member named ‘UnsafeArenaRelease’
   return to_tensor_.UnsafeArenaRelease(&::google::protobuf::internal::GetEmptyS
                     ^
/usr/local/include/tf/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.pb.h: In member function ‘void tensorflow::TensorConnection::unsafe_arena_set_allocated_to_tensor(std::__cxx11::string*)’:
/usr/local/include/tf/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.pb.h:6462:14: error: ‘struct google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr’ has no member named ‘UnsafeArenaSetAllocated’
   to_tensor_.UnsafeArenaSetAllocated(&::google::protobuf::internal::GetEmptyStr
              ^
/usr/local/include/tf/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.pb.h: In member function ‘int tensorflow::CallableOptions::feed_devices_size() const’:
/usr/local/include/tf/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.pb.h:6779:24: error: request for member ‘size’ in ‘((const tensorflow::CallableOptions*)this)->tensorflow::CallableOptions::feed_devices_’, which is of non-class type ‘const int’
   return feed_devices_.size();
                        ^
/usr/local/include/tf/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.pb.h: In member function ‘void tensorflow::CallableOptions::clear_feed_devices()’:
/usr/local/include/tf/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.pb.h:6782:17: error: request for member ‘Clear’ in ‘((tensorflow::CallableOptions*)this)->tensorflow::CallableOptions::feed_devices_’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
   feed_devices_.Clear();
                 ^
/usr/local/include/tf/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.pb.h: In member function ‘const google::protobuf::Map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >& tensorflow::CallableOptions::feed_devices() const’:
/usr/local/include/tf/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.pb.h:6787:24: error: request for member ‘GetMap’ in ‘((const tensorflow::CallableOptions*)this)->tensorflow::CallableOptions::feed_devices_’, which is of non-class type ‘const int’
   return feed_devices_.GetMap();
                        ^
/usr/local/include/tf/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.pb.h: In member function ‘google::protobuf::Map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >* tensorflow::CallableOptions::mutable_feed_devices()’:
/usr/local/include/tf/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.pb.h:6792:24: error: request for member ‘MutableMap’ in ‘((tensorflow::CallableOptions*)this)->tensorflow::CallableOptions::feed_devices_’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
   return feed_devices_.MutableMap();
                        ^
/usr/local/include/tf/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.pb.h: In member function ‘int tensorflow::CallableOptions::fetch_devices_size() const’:
/usr/local/include/tf/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.pb.h:6797:25: error: request for member ‘size’ in ‘((const tensorflow::CallableOptions*)this)->tensorflow::CallableOptions::fetch_devices_’, which is of non-class type ‘const int’
   return fetch_devices_.size();
                         ^
/usr/local/include/tf/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.pb.h: In member function ‘void tensorflow::CallableOptions::clear_fetch_devices()’:
/usr/local/include/tf/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.pb.h:6800:18: error: request for member ‘Clear’ in ‘((tensorflow::CallableOptions*)this)->tensorflow::CallableOptions::fetch_devices_’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
   fetch_devices_.Clear();
                  ^
/usr/local/include/tf/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.pb.h: In member function ‘const google::protobuf::Map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >& tensorflow::CallableOptions::fetch_devices() const’:
/usr/local/include/tf/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.pb.h:6805:25: error: request for member ‘GetMap’ in ‘((const tensorflow::CallableOptions*)this)->tensorflow::CallableOptions::fetch_devices_’, which is of non-class type ‘const int’
   return fetch_devices_.GetMap();
                         ^
/usr/local/include/tf/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.pb.h: In member function ‘google::protobuf::Map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >* tensorflow::CallableOptions::mutable_fetch_devices()’:
/usr/local/include/tf/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.pb.h:6810:25: error: request for member ‘MutableMap’ in ‘((tensorflow::CallableOptions*)this)->tensorflow::CallableOptions::fetch_devices_’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
   return fetch_devices_.MutableMap();
                         ^
CMakeFiles/speech_recog.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/speech_recog.dir/label_wav.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/speech_recog.dir/label_wav.cc.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/speech_recog.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/speech_recog.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Now getting these errors

Answer (score 0):

now getting these errors

Scanning dependencies of target speech_recog
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/speech_recog.dir/label_wav.cc.o
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable speech_recog
CMakeFiles/speech_recog.dir/label_wav.cc.o: In function `tensorflow::Status tensorflow::errors::NotFound<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, char const*>(char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, char const*)': label_wav.cc:(.text._ZN10tensorflow6errors8NotFoundIJPKcNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES3_EEENS_6StatusEDpT_[_ZN10tensorflow6errors8NotFoundIJPKcNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES3_EEENS_6StatusEDpT_]+0xe5): undefined reference to` tensorflow::Status::Status(tensorflow::error::Code, absl::string_view, std::vector<tensorflow::StackFrame, std::allocatortensorflow::StackFrame >&&)'
CMakeFiles/speech_recog.dir/label_wav.cc.o: In function `main': label_wav.cc:(.text.startup+0x1219): undefined reference to` tensorflow::TensorShapeBasetensorflow::TensorShape::TensorShapeBase(absl::Span)'
label_wav.cc:(.text.startup+0x1f55): undefined reference to `tensorflow::TensorShapeBase<tensorflow::TensorShape>::TensorShapeBase(absl::Span<long long const>)' label_wav.cc:(.text.startup+0x1fa8): undefined reference to` tensorflow::TensorShapeBasetensorflow::TensorShape::TensorShapeBase(absl::Span)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/speech_recog.dir/build.make:114: recipe for target 'speech_recog' failed
make[2]: *** [speech_recog] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/speech_recog.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/speech_recog.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2